# Is a unitary opertor with $\sigma(U)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$ necessarily be the identity?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

In a complex, infinite dimensional, separable Hilbert space, we have a unitary operator $U\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ with only one element in its spectrum: $\sigma(U)=\lbrace 1\rbrace$.
Is it true, that $U=I$?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Are you familiar with the spectral theorem for bounded, normal operators ?

Comment: I've learnt it, why? Can I use it?

Comment: I was mistaken, sorry. I thought you might be able to obtain an ONB of eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $1$ (in which case you'd be done). This might still be true, but it doesn't immediately follow from the spectral theorem for normal operators.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gelfand transform? From it you can see that if a normal element of a $C^*$ algebra has a spectrum consisting of one point, then it must be proportional to the identity.

Comment: Or in other words, the "multiplication operator" version of the spectral theorem for normal operators.  You find that $U$ is equivalent to multiplication by a function whose range is $\{1\}$, which must thus be the constant function 1.  The projection-valued measure form should also work: you would find the projection-valued measure would be supported on $\{1\}$, so it must be a "point mass".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $U$ is a unitary operator, $U-I$ is normal, so using Gelfand's spectral radius formula:
$$0\le\Vert U-I\Vert=r(U-I)=\max\lbrace\lambda~\vert~\lambda\in\sigma(U-I)\rbrace\le\max\lbrace\lambda~\vert~\lambda\in\sigma(U)-\sigma(I)\rbrace=0$$
This implies $U=I$.

(The $\sigma(U-I)\subset\sigma(U)-\sigma(I)$ relation holds because $U$ and $I$ are commuting elements of a C*-algebra.)